# procfile for heroku and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, foreman, procfile

I am little confused on the usage of the `Procfile` on development in local machine and in heroku

In order to start rails in my local machine I need

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT

worker:  bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

which works when I use `foreman`

but heroku runs

```
bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 48378
```

What do I write in the `Procfile` so it would be fine for my local machine and for heroku?

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive filesystem locally (Windows or Mac)? Try renaming `procfile` to `Procfile`.

Comment: the content of the procfile is more important in this case

Comment: Heroku is running the [default process for Rails apps](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/v50/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb#L21), which suggests it isn’t seeing your `procfile`. If it’s named `procfile` then Heroku (which is on case-sensitive Linux) won’t see it.

Comment: On *nix file names are case-sensitive. ...and make sure you have `gem 'thin'` in your Gemfile.